# Reposition a sprite relative to its parents position

Tags: javascript, rotation, position, sprite

This is an HTML5/JavaScript game development related question.
I need to rotate a parent sprite and keep its child sprite's position and rotation correctly aligned.
So if the parent rotates, the child should maintain the correct position and rotation.

Does anyone know what the formula for this is?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know about the object's local and world coordinates, so you can keep track of the parent-child relationship. It is not as easy as it seems if you want to do animation, but here's an example. The "formula" you're looking for is in `b.pos`, to calculate to position relative to the parent object.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/dahul/2/edit

```
// Some basic canvas utilities
// (see demo)

// Objects to be drawn on canvas
var a = {
  x: 0, // global coordinates
  y: 0, // ^
  vx: .1, // velocity
  vy: .1, // ^
  w: 100, // dimensions
  h: 100, // ^
  color: 'red'
};

var b = {
  parent: a, // relationship
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  lx: .5, // local coordinates (percentage)
  ly: .5, // ^
  w: 25,
  h: 25,
  color: 'yellow',
  pos: function() { // calculate position relative to given parent
    return {
      x: this.parent.w * this.lx - this.w / 2,
      y: this.parent.h * this.ly - this.h / 2
    };
  }
};

// Draw boxes with parent-child relationship
// @param a {Object} Parent
// @param b {Object} Child
var draw = function(a, b, ctx, dt) {
  ctx.fillStyle = a.color;
  ctx.fillRect(a.x += a.vx * dt, a.y += a.vy * dt, a.w, a.h);
  ctx.fillStyle = b.color;
  ctx.fillRect(b.x + a.x + b.pos().x, b.y + a.y + b.pos().y, b.w, b.h);
};

// Initialize and animate canvas
document.body.appendChild(canvas(400, 400, function(ctx) {
  return render(function(dt) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    draw(a, b, ctx, dt);
  });
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand the code, but it doesn't include rotation. If the child is offset from the parent's center, and the parent is rotated, how would the child be re-positioned?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you keep the logic it should work. You rotate the whole canvas, do your operations, and restore the rotation if needed, for example http://jsbin.com/sazes/2/edit

Comment: Thank you, I understand this perfectly now and your solution works with my code! The mistake I was making was to try and do all these transforms in the application code. I hadn't considered just letting the canvas do it. I save() on the parent sprite and then loop through its children and renderi them using their local coordinates. Then restore() when the parent and children are done rendering.

Comment: What about rotation? Could you please provide the same example but for rotation? It looks too me mush harder than position